# Scan from text file

Tags: java

I am trying to print a multiple information from a text file like print the nameOfEmployee, hourlyRate, hoursWorked, taxRate, grossAmount, netAmount but it only gives me java.util.InputMismatchException and in the console not all of the information from a employee is printed only the name, hourlyRate, hoursWorked, taxRate, also i want to Total all the  grossAmount  of my employees.

```
    private static Scanner ian; 

    public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scan();
    }

    public static void Scan()
    {
        try 
        {
            ian = new Scanner(new File("payroll.dat")); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e)       
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(ian.hasNext())
        {
            String a = ian.nextLine();
            int b = ian.nextInt();
            int c = ian.nextInt();
            int d = ian.nextInt();
            int e = ian.nextInt();
            int f = ian.nextInt();

            System.out.printf("a= ", a , "b= ", b , " c= ", c , " d= ", d , "e = ",  e , "f = "  ,f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To get correct reason for exception you should wrap up your code inside `try` and `catch` block , not only during Scanner Class instantiation

Comment: Almost sure you don't need the ian.nextLine(), nextInt should go in newline by itself. Also, you sure all the values are int, not decimals?

Comment: Well clearly there is a mismatch between what is in the file and how you are reading it!  But unless you show us some input, we can't tell you why.

Comment: *"...  also i want to Total all the grossAmount of my employees."* - Well Java isn't a telepathic programming language, so you will need to write some code to do that.

Comment: @Diego Martinoia . i think decimals also , my error is just when i input from text file of a of more than one Employee details it do not print out all the more than one Employee Details and the information i entered from the text file and it only show the employeeName, hourlyRate, hoursWorked, . just only the three of the 6 will be printed if the execution is successful.

Comment: put your data sample also

Comment: it should be like these employeeName 50 15 20 45 20...50 for hourlyRate , 15 for hoursWorked ,   20 taxRate, 45 for grossAmount and 20 for netAmount . these is the input from the text file and but it won't printout all the information i have entered .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please do refer 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

Edited code...
The complete signature of printf is printf(String format, Object... args). The first argument is a String that describes the desired formatting of the output. From there on, printf can have multiple number of arguments of any type. At runtime, these arguments will be converted to String and will be printed according to the formatting instructions.
1.%d  for integers and %s for String:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;




public class readfile {
    private static Scanner ian;

    public static void main (String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scan();
    }

    public static void Scan()
    {
        try
        {
            ian = new Scanner(new File("demo.txt"));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(ian.hasNext())
        {

            int b = ian.nextInt();
            int c = ian.nextInt();
            int d = ian.nextInt();
            int e = ian.nextInt();
            int f = ian.nextInt();
            String a = ian.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("a : %s, b : %d, c : %d ,d : %d ,e  : %d, g : %d "  ,a,b,c,d,e,f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a= : employeeName , this only gives me not all the detail

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the printf line by something like :

```
System.out.printf("a= %d b= %d c= %d d= %d e = %d f = %d"  ,a,b,c,d,e,f);
```

printf take as first argument the String format, and then other argument to be formatted inside

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Yes ,,, but this isn't what is causing the exception.

Comment: i tried it but this is the only output  "a=" not all the values

Answer (score 0):

How about reading from file in java 7 style?

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
    try(Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("payroll.dat"))){
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            // extract data here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It gives me this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Try.main(Try.java:17)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for `Scanner` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

`nextLine()`: "Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped."

You're checking if there is more input with `hasNext()`, but then you call `nextLine()` which will skip (and return) the entire next line. Then you call `nextInt()`, but after your last line, there won't be any more integers.

You probably want something like this:

```
while(ian.hasNextLine())
    {
        int b = ian.nextInt();
        int c = ian.nextInt();
        int d = ian.nextInt();
        int e = ian.nextInt();
        int f = ian.nextInt();
        String a = ian.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("a= ", a , "b= ", b , " c= ", c , " d= ", d , "e = ",  e , "f = "  ,f);
    }
}
```

but it depends on the format of your file, which you haven't posted.

Answer (score 0):

this is the original , i tried that because i want to know if it's just the original is wrong , I'm sorry for not clearing my question and not being specifically hope you can help guys .

```
private static final double FULL_TIME = 40.0;

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

static String nameOfEmployee;
static double hourlyRate;
static double hoursWorked;
static double taxRate;
static double grossAmount = 0;
static double netAmount = 0;

static double TOtalGrossAmount = 0;
static double TotalNetAmount = 0;

private static Scanner ian;



public static void main (String []args) throws IOException

    {

        Instructions();

        PayrollReport();

        printEmployeeInfo(nameOfEmployee, hourlyRate, hoursWorked, taxRate, grossAmount, netAmount);

    }



public static void Instructions()

{
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tInstructions for Payroll Report Program" +
            "\n\t\t\t\tThis program calculates a paycheck for each employee." +
            "\n\t\t\t\tA text file containing the following information will be created." +
            "\n\t\t\t\tname, pay rate, hours worked, and tax percentage to be deducted");

    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tThe program will create a report in columnar format showing the " +
            "\n\t\t\t\ttemployee name, hourly rate, number of worked, tax rate," +
            "\n\t\t\t\tgross pay, and netpay.");

    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\tAfter all emplyoees are processed , totals will be displayed," +
            "\n\t\t\t\tincluding total gross amount and total net pay.");
}

public static void PayrollReport()
{
    {
       System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tPayroll Report ");
       System.out.print("");

       System.out.print("\n\t\t\t\tEmployee Name " + "  Hourly Rate " + " Hours Worked " + " Tax Rate " + " Gross Amount " + " Net Amount");

       System.out.print("");
       System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t--------------- " + " ----------- " + " ------------" + " --------- " + " ----------- " + " -----------");         
    }       
}

public static void printEmployeeInfo(String nameOfEmployee , double HourlyRate , double HoursWorked ,
        double TaxRate , double GrossAmount , double NetAmount ) throws IOException 
    {

        try 
            {

            ian = new Scanner(new File("payroll.dat")); 

            } 

        catch (IOException e)       

        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    while (ian.hasNext())       
    {
        nameOfEmployee = ian.nextLine();
        HourlyRate = ian.nextInt();
        HoursWorked = ian.nextInt();
        TaxRate = ian.nextInt();
        GrossAmount = 0;
        NetAmount = 0;

         TOtalGrossAmount += GrossAmount ;
         TotalNetAmount += NetAmount;

        System.out.printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s \n" , "\t\t\t\t" , nameOfEmployee , " "
                , HourlyRate , "   " , HoursWorked , " " , TaxRate , GrossAmount, NetAmount );       
    }

    System.out.printf(" " , TOtalGrossAmount + " " + TotalNetAmount);

        ian.close();
    }
```

}